# Push a link with Pushbullet and have it automatically opened in web browser

Tags: android, pushbullet

I'm trying to use Pushbullet to send links from Android app which should automatically open in web browser.

Their API states that you have to use `"type": "link"` when you're going to send a link. I've tried this, but the link isn't automatically opened in the browser, you have to click the notification to open it.

Here's the command:

> curl --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' -X POST
>   https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes --header 'Content-Type:
>   application/json' --data-binary '{"type": "link", "title": "Note
>   Title", "body": "Note Body", "url": "http://google.com"}'

What I want is exactly the same behavior as Pushbullet offers for Chrome on Android. You just share a page using "A New Push" action and it's automatically opened in web browser. Is it possible with current API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pushbullet apps will only automatically open links if they are sent directly to that device and not just the user.  So to get the link to open automatically you should set `"device_iden": "<device iden for your browser>"`.  You can find the device iden by going to https://www.pushbullet.com/ and clicking on your device on the left.  The url will change to `https://www.pushbullet.com/?device_iden=<device iden>` and you can use that device iden in your request.

Comment: You can get your devices by running this command:
`curl --header 'Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>'   https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/devices`

or in Windows
`curl -H "Access-Token: <your_access_token>" https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/devices`